# regexp for word "port" following space and number

Tags: regex, qregexp

I am working on subclassed [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html):

```
UeSyntaxHiglighter::UeSyntaxHiglighter(QTextDocument* const parent)
    : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent)
{
    UeHighlightRule ruleInfo;
    UeHighlightRule ruleWarning;
    UeHighlightRule ruleError;
    UeHighlightRule ruleIPv4Address;
    UeHighlightRule rulePortNumber;
    UeHighlightRule ruleProtocolCommand;
    UeHighlightRule ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledge;

    QTextCharFormat ruleInfoFormat;
    QTextCharFormat ruleWarningFormat;
    QTextCharFormat ruleErrorFormat;;
    QTextCharFormat ruleIPv4AddressFormat;
    QTextCharFormat ruleProtocolCommandFormat;
    QTextCharFormat ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledgeFormat;

    ruleInfoFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkBlue);
    ruleInfoFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::ExtraLight);
    ruleInfo.pattern=QRegExp("^\\[INFO\\].*");
    ruleInfo.format=ruleInfoFormat;

    ruleWarningFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkYellow);
    ruleWarningFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Normal);
    ruleWarning.pattern=QRegExp("^\\[WARNING\\].*");
    ruleWarning.format=ruleWarningFormat;

    ruleErrorFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkRed);
    ruleErrorFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::ExtraBold);
    ruleError.pattern=QRegExp("^\\[ERROR\\].*");
    ruleError.format=ruleErrorFormat;

    ruleIPv4AddressFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::ExtraBold);
    ruleIPv4Address.pattern=QRegExp("(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})");
    ruleIPv4Address.format=ruleIPv4AddressFormat;

    //BUG apply same coloring rule to port number as IP address
    rulePortNumber.pattern=QRegExp("\\d+$");
    rulePortNumber.format=ruleIPv4AddressFormat;

    ruleProtocolCommandFormat.setFontCapitalization(QFont::AllUppercase);
    ruleProtocolCommandFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::ExtraBold);
    ruleProtocolCommandFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkGreen);
    //BUG rule is not applied, i.e. text coloring is not active
    ruleProtocolCommand.pattern=QRegExp("^CMD.\\*");
    ruleProtocolCommand.format=ruleProtocolCommandFormat;

    ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledgeFormat.setFontCapitalization(QFont::AllUppercase);
    ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledgeFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::ExtraBold);
    ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledgeFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkMagenta);
    //BUG rule is not applied, i.e. text coloring is not active
    ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledge.pattern=QRegExp("^ACK.\\*");
    ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledge.format=ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledgeFormat;

    m_ueHighlightRules.append(ruleInfo);
    m_ueHighlightRules.append(ruleWarning);
    m_ueHighlightRules.append(ruleError);
    m_ueHighlightRules.append(ruleIPv4Address);
    m_ueHighlightRules.append(rulePortNumber);
    m_ueHighlightRules.append(ruleProtocolCommand);
    m_ueHighlightRules.append(ruleProtocolCommandAcknowledge);
}
```

Now, in app which is using this class, I have following sample log [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details):

> New incoming connection from host with IP address 192.168.1.4 using
>   port 56748

What is the regular expression for **port number** (number **at the end of string**, which is following word *port* - case sensitive) **AND** excatly  **ONE** whitespace?

Comment: What is the pattern you tried and that did not work? Also, is there a possibility that the word `port` is followed with arbitrary number of whitespaces?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've tried `rulePortNumber.pattern=QRegExp("\\d+$");`, however, it colors me **every** number at the end of **every** log string.

Comment: That's true. If you have just 1 space between the number and `port`, you can try `(?<=\\bport )\\d+$`. However, this approach won't work if there can be 1 or more spaces, you'd need a capturing approach: `\\bport +(\\d+)$` (and access the capture #1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\d+$` regex will match 1 or more digits at the end of the string, regardless of the left-hand context.

You should consider using a *capturing* approach: `"\\bport +(\\d+)$"` (and access the capture #1). That will require some code adjustment though.

The reason is that [QRegExp does not support a lookbehind](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#perl-users):

> Both zero-width positive and zero-width negative lookahead assertions `(?=pattern)` and `(?!pattern)` are supported with the same syntax as Perl. **Perl's lookbehind assertions**, "independent" subexpressions and conditional expressions **are *not* supported**.

The space can be replaced with `[ \t]` if you only need to match ASCII horizontal whitespace (or you may try an `\s` with `\r` and `\n` excluded - `"[^\\S\r\n]"`).

Comment: Note I used string literals for the suggested patterns (hence double backslashes), while the regexes explained are just used inside backticks shown as code (and have single backslashes).

Comment: Also, if you had access to `QRegularExpression` in Qt5, you could use a better suited `\bport[ \t]+\K\d+$`.

Comment: Yes, that is true, I've followed [Syntax Highlighter Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you couldn't use something like `port \d+$` ?

Comment: I've tried `port \d+$`, however it colors me **both** word *port* **AND** following number.